# 'This post has been deleted' appears above the flag bar

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, deleted-posts, waffle-bar

When a post is deleted and the notification comes through, it scrolls over the inline flag bar:

[image]

The entire post also seems to capture clicks instead of letting them get to the flag bar. Looks like someone got a z-index wrong...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not when I delete another answer, then the obnoxious box floats over my tools while I try to decline the other flag.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. Same cause, perhaps, but different issue.