# "This post has been deleted" box's Z-Index is too high, overlaps dialog overlays and looks weird

Tags: bug, design, deleted-posts, overlap

Screenshot tells more than 1000 words:

[image]

(Oh and I think it's not an exact duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278822/this-post-has-been-deleted-appears-above-the-flag-bar) because it's only about overlapping parts of the post's content including flag bar if I read it correctly, not about overlapping UI which should be above it because it's a floating dialog box - although it probably has the same cause.)